# Tengo una duda con el siguiente programa

Tags: java, excepciones, enum

> La clase Task tiene un constructor con argumentos que inicializa los
> valores de  los  atributos  de  la  clase.  Si  el  valor  del
> parámetro  workload  pasado  como  argumento es negativo o mayor que
> 100, entonces debe lanzar una excepción del  tipo
> IllegalArgumentException (es una clase propia de la API de Java) con
> el mensaje "[ERROR] Task's parameter is incorrect!!". Por otro lado,
> si el valor del parámetro name pasado como argumento, no cumple un
> patrón de  nombre establecido, también debe lanzar la misma excepción.
> El  patrón  de  nombre  que  buscamos  para  name  es:  T,  seguido
> de  cualquier  número, seguido de : y por último, seguido de un String
> (o no) que describa  la tarea.
>
> Ten en cuenta que IllegalArgumentException es una unchecked exception
> y, por consiguiente, no es obligatorio ni lanzar  la  excepción  ni
> capturarla.  No  obstante,  nosotros  queremos  que  el  constructor
> lance “hacia arriba” (i.e. a quien le ha llamado) dicha excepción.

No se donde cometo el error, se agradece ayuda.

```
public enum TaskType {
    
    MANAGEMENT,
    FUNCTIONAL,
    TECHNICAL,
    ISSUE;

}
```

```
public class Task {
    
    private String name;
    private int workload;
    TaskType type;
    String msg = "[ERROR] Task's parameter is incorrect!!";
    
    
    public Task(String name, int workload, TaskType type) {
                
        this.name = validateName(name);
        
        this.workload = workload;
    }
    
    public String validateName(String name) {
        String patron = "T[0-9]:[ a-zA-Z0-9]";
        if(!name.matches(patron)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
            }
        return msg;
        }


    public int getWorkload() {
        return workload;
    }


    public void setWorkload(int workload) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        
        if (workload < 0 || workload >= 100) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
        }else{
            this.workload = workload;
        }
    }


    public String getName() {   
        
        return name;
    }


    public TaskType getType() {
        return type;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        
        return "("+this.getType()+") " + this.getName() +" - workload "+this.getWorkload()+"%";
    }
    
    

    
}
```

Comment: Podrías aclarar específicamente cúal es el error o la duda que tenes?

Comment: Mi duda es que al validar name tengo que enviar la excepción, por ejemplo new Task("tarea 1", 20, TaskType.FUNCTIONAL)); 
y me lance: "[ERROR] Task's parameter is incorrect!!", he cambiado algo el código pero sigue igual y ya no se por donde seguir..

Answer (score -1):

No entiendo del todo tu duda/error pero noto un par de cosas a grandes rasgos:

1. En el constructor cuando se pasa el atributo `name` le estas asignado lo devuelto por la función `validateName()` y no el valor que te pasaron originalmente. Es decir, que si hace el "match" del patrón en lugar de guardar ese valor se va a asignar a `name` lo definido por `msg` en `String msg = "[ERROR] Task's parameter is incorrect!!";`
2. En el constructor al atributo `workload` lo asignas tal como viene sin validar. Nota que la validación la tenes solo en el `setWorkload()`. Es decir, que tranquilamente puede aceptar un valor negativo o mayor a 100.
3. El constructor recibe un `TaskType` y nunca lo utiliza.

**Edicion** luego de leer tu comentario que aclara el problema:

> Mi duda es que al validar name tengo que enviar la excepción, por ejemplo new Task("tarea 1", 20, TaskType.FUNCTIONAL)); y me lance: "[ERROR] Task's parameter is incorrect!!", he cambiado algo el código pero sigue igual y ya no se por donde seguir..

Por lo que leo ahora de tu comentario el problema es con la expresión regular que estas utilizando. Pensaba que eso estaba bien y tu error problema iba por otro lado...en fin intenta con esta regex

`T:[ a-zA-Z0-9]\w+`

Notar que esta expresión tal y como lo tenes en tu ejemplo de código (pero no en la consigna) puede aceptar un espacio en blanco luego de los 2 puntos.

Con la expresión **\w** indicás que **[ a-zA-Z0-9]** coincida con cualquier caracter o palabra y el **+** para que coincida con uno o mas del token anterior (**\w**)